# ASP.NET Session Expires immediately after Login

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have developed an ASP.NET application using Visual Studio 2017, everything works fine on my development PC (Win 7 & IIS 7.5), but when moving the application to the production server (Windows server 2019 & IIS 10), I faced the following issues:

1. It takes long time to load the Login Page.
2. When the Login page is loaded, I enter the username and Password, the normal behavior is to redirect to another page, but unfortunately I find that the session is died, and the app redirects again to the login page.

Noting that:

- The app pool is not recycled.
- No amendments done on the web.config.
- No changes in the bin folder of the app.

Is there any problem related to the windows 2019 since I have't deploy on 2019 before, or what could be the problem.

Comment: this is a cookie issue - check the `domain` parameter on your `web.config` that is correct

Comment: I have put the following in the web.config, but unfortunately didn't work:
<system.web>
   <httpCookies domain=".domain.com"/>
</system.web>

Comment: You could set the session time out in IIS manager->site node->session state. Or <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30"/> to set the session time out in web.config. <sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="480" can also set the time out.

Comment: @ImadAbuHayyah Place `domain="domain.com"` (without the dot) also on `authentication` and on `roleManager`